# Find $A$ that $A^2 = I$ and $A^T = A$ and $Ax = y$ for given $x,y$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $x,y$:

> $x = [4,-3,5]$ , $y = [-4,3,-5]$
>
> $x = [4,-3,5]$ , $y= [5,5,0]$
>
> $x = [4,-3,5]$ , $y = [5,0,0]$

Find $A$ that $A^2 = I$ and $A^T = A$ and $Ax = y$, if you cant find $A$ explain why.

So for first one it is easy because $y = -x$, Thuse $Ax = -X$ and $A = -I$

For third, I think we can't find $A$ because $A$ has to be the reflection matrix, thus $Ax,y$ must be orthogonal to each other, and I believe we can't find such $A$, I don't know exactly why we can't find it. I believe that ||Ax|| = ||x|| and thus $y$ has to be atleast with $2$ coordinates that are not zero. and they must be atleast $x,y$ coordinates.

Comment: We work in a two-dimensional vector space?

Comment: @MooS I believe $A , x , y \in R^3 $

Comment: $A$ is a linear map. How is this supposed to be contained in $\mathbb R^3$?. You mean $A: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @MooS if we take a matrix $3x3$ and multiply with vector $3x1$ we get a vector $3x1$. thus $A$ is composed of vectors in $R^3$

Comment: Im fully aware of this. Nevertheless the statement $A \in \mathbb R^3$ is not even close to be true.

Comment: @MooS Obviously... but how does it advance us to the solution?

Comment: @MooS How about $||Ax|| = ||x|| = ||y||$, thus third one can't be solved. second one can be solved. I solved it, thanks for wasting my time on useless questions.

Comment: I could easily answer your question, but thanks to your last comment, I will not. Good luck finding someone who is willing to answer.

Comment: @MooS I just solved it in my previous comment.

Comment: @MooS And about $A \in R^3$, I meant $A \in R^{3x3}$ , was to lazy to write it. Which again, doesn't advance us to the solution. because it is trivial.

Comment: It is also trivial that posing questions with precise notations does actually advance you to a solution. Because people, which are able to solve your problem, will be more motivated to help you. Keep on spoiling potential helpers, if you are fine with it. Furthermore, you accepted an incomplete answer and you obviously haven't fully solved the problem yet.

Comment: @MooS His answer is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $\|Ax\|^2=(Ax)^\top(Ax)=x^\top(A^\top A)x=x^\top x=\|x\|$, so the third one is impossible.

For the second one, the magnitudes coincide, and the normal of the required reflection plane points along the difference of the two vectors, $(1,8,-5)$. This needs to be normalised to $n=\frac1{\sqrt{90}}(1,8,-5)$, yielding

$$
A=I-2nn^\top=\frac1{90}\pmatrix{88&-16&10\\-16&-38&80\\10&80&40}\;.
$$

Comment: Why $y - x = n$? and why $A = I - 2nn^T$ will find us $A$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: For the first question, imagine the two vectors on a sheet of paper and placing a mirror perpendicular to the paper along their bisector. For the second question, $nn^\top x$ is the component of $x$ along the unit normal vector, and we need to subtract this twice to reverse its sign.

Comment: I see, it comes from $R = 2P - I$, thus $R = I - 2nn^T = A$.

Comment: I think I can find $n$ with determinant on two vectors, I mean determinant of $x X y$ , meaning $x $ cross $y$, right?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: I don't know what you mean by the determinant of $x\times y$. (You can get the symbol for the cross product using `\times`.) Perhaps you're thinking of a vector normal to both $x$ and $y$? That's not what we need here.

Comment: a vector that is orthogonal to $x$ and $y$ that is what I meant, which is a result of cross product of vectors $x,y$. but it is the normal of the reflection plane as you said

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Note that I calculated only the reflection; there is also a rotation through $\pi$ about $x+y$, which is $2uu^\top-I$, where $u$ is a unit vector along $x+y$; this is the other matrix given in Dietrich Burde's answer. Your second comment above seems to first assume the equation for this rotation, $R=2P-I$, but then switches to the equation for the reflection, $R=I-2P$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question we can take $A=-I_3$; for the second there are exactly two solutions, namely
$$
A=\frac{1}{55} \begin{pmatrix} 26 & 18 & 45 \\  18 & -51 & 10 \\ 45 & 10 &   -30\end{pmatrix}, \quad A=\frac{1}{45} \begin{pmatrix} 44 & -8 & 5 \\  -8 & -19 & 40 \\ 5 & 40 &   20\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This follows from a direct computation, assuming a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix $A$ satisfying $A^2=I_3$.
The third question has no solution.